# Change colour of button when input fields are filled

Tags: javascript, html, button, colors

I open a div with a table inside by clicking a button. In this table there are a number of input fields. If all input fields are filled then button should change the colour.

I have a number of divs with table with input fields. One of them is working, but does not succeed with seccond div.

```
<p><br></p> 

<!-- The Next Button Plates -->
<button id = "buttonP" onclick="showOrHide('Plates')" class="button1" name= "Plates" ><b>Plates</b></button> 
<!-- Insert a table in a div, so this can be hide -->
 <div id="Plates">
<br>    
<div id="CompoundPlates_button">
 <table style="width:20%;margin-left:50px;" >
 <colgroup>
    <col span="3" style="background-color:#E3CEF6;">
    <!--<col style="background-color:yellow"> -->
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td width="20%"><input type="button" id = "button" class="buttonsmall" style="height:20px;width:60px" onclick="showOrHide('CompoundPlates')">      
    </td>
    <td width="40%"><b>CompoundPlates</></td>
    <td width="15%"></td> 
    <td width="15%"></td>
    <td width="10%"></td>   
  </tr> 
  </table>
 </div> <!-- Close Div CompoundPlates_button --> 
         <!-- Insert a table in a div, so this can be hide -->
 <div id="CompoundPlates">
   <table style="width:50%;margin-left:50px;" >
        <colgroup>
        <col span="3" style="background-color:#E3CEF6;">        
        </colgroup>
   <tr>
    <td  width="10%">      
    </td>
    <td  width="20%">Number of Plates:</td>
    <td  width="30%"><input type="text" name="Number of plates" size="35"></td> 
    <td  width="20%"></td>
    <td  width="20%"></td>  
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>      
    </td>
    <td>Plate/Tip type :</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Plate/Tip type" size="35"></td> 
    <td></td>
    <td></td>   
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>Lid : </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Lid" size="35"> </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>Storage device :</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Storage device" size="35"></td> 
    <td></td>
    <td></td>   
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>Position :</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Position" size="35"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>    
  </tr> 
 </table>
 </div> <!-- Close div CompoundPlates -->
</div> <!-- Close div Plates -->
```

If input boxes are filled then color of button Compound plates should change from red to green. And if button Compound plates and button Assay plates is green then overlaying button Plates should also change from red to green

Comment: Can you share the code that you tried to execute this behavior (I am guessing a JS script)? That would help see where you might have made a mistake

Answer (score 0):

I think it's helpful for you

**[1]: [Change the button's color after fill out the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49150763/change-the-buttons-color-after-fill-out-the-form)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type=text]").change(function() {
  var filled = true;
  $( "input[type=text]" ).each(function( index ) {
  if($( this ).val() == ""){
    filled = false;
  });
  if(filled === false){
    //change color
  }
});
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: It don't know much about javascript and it is not clear to me howto adjust your code to get it do the job. Can you look at my code and let me know where to adjust the javascript of you

Answer (score 0):

What I did is I used Jquery to check and change the color of the button and for the input fields I used css because it was hard for me to change more than one input field. This is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mLu1d6sx/2/)

```js
$("input[type='text'], textarea").on("input", function () { canChangeColor(); }); function canChangeColor(){ var can = true; $("input[type='text'], textarea").each(function(){ if($(this).val()==''){ can = false; } }); if(can){ $('.btn').css({background:'green'}) }else{ $('.btn').css({background:'red'}) } }
```

```css
.form-control {
  background-color: red;
}

.form-control:valid {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="user_name"  placeholder="  Full Name" required>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_mail" placeholder="  Email Address" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="user_message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder=" Let me know what's on your mind" required></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
 <div class="sendButton">
      <button class="btn" type="submit" disabled="disabled">Send</button>
    </div>
```

Hope this works for you!

Comment: It don't know much about javascript and it is not clear to me howto adjust your code to get it do the job.  Can you look at my code and let me know where to adjust the javascript of you

Comment: @Orca first you have to include jquery like in the code (has to be in the head) and above in the body use `<script></script>` and between the script you add the javascript